# calling a parameter in a different python module

Tags: python

I am trying to call Branchname defined in test.py from test1.py and running into following error,can anyone provide inputs?

test.py

```
import test1
import os
import sys
def main():
    #initialize global variables & read CMD line arguments
    global BranchName
    ScriptDir = os.getcwd()
    print ScriptDir
    BranchName  = sys.argv[1]
    print "BranchName"
    print BranchName
    #Update input file with external gerrits, if any
    print "Before running test1"
    test1.main()
    print "After running test1"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

test1.py

```
import test
def main ():
    print test.BranchName
```

Running into following error

```
BranchName
ab_mr2
Before running test1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 14, in main
    test1.main()
  File "/local/mnt/workspace/test1.py", line 3, in main
    print test.BranchName
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BranchName
```

Comment: You have a circular import here, which is never good. Is there a reason the code is split up like this?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid - my goal is to print BranchName passed to test.py from test1.py..

Comment: You arent passing anything here.

Comment: You have a test.py that is the main script you call. Then you don't run test.py, but run test1.py instead. but still assume that test.py is the main function. That doesn't really make any sense, and I think you should think about how you split things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my goal is to print BranchName passed to test.py from test1.py

If this is your case, then your file names are reversed. Also, you aren't passing anything around (which you should, instead of playing with `global`).

In `test1.py`, calculate `BranchName`, and then *pass it* to the `main` method from `test`.

```
import os
import sys

import test

def main():
    ScriptDir = os.getcwd()
    print ScriptDir
    BranchName  = sys.argv[1]
    print "BranchName"
    print BranchName
    #Update input file with external gerrits, if any
    print "Before running test1"
    test.main(BranchName) # here I am passing the variable
    print "After running test1"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In `test.py`, you have simply:

```
def main(branch_name):
    print('In test.py, the value is: {0}', branch_name)
```

Comment: is there a way to get this using "if __name__ == '__main__':" in test.py in your above script..

Comment: You put that line in whatever script you want to call as a starting point. The script that is setting `ScriptDir` is the starting point, which is why its in `test1.py`. If you put this line in `test.py`, you'll get an error because you won't have anything to pass to `main` (`ScriptDir` won't be set).

Answer (score 4):

`main()` does not actually get called in your test.py, because `__name__ != '__main__'`.

If you print `__name__`, it is actually `test`.

This is a reason why many scripts have the `if __name__ == '__main__'`, so if it is imported, the whole code isn't run.

To fix this, you have to do two things:

- You can just remove the `if __name__ == '__main__':` in your `test.py`, and just replace it with `main()`
- There is no need to `import test1.py` in your test. In doing so, this is actually running `main()` in your `test1.py`, and will thus raise an error because `test.BranchName` hasn't even been defined yet.

  - However, if you must import `test1.py`, you can actually put an `if __name__ == '__main__'` in there, so when you import it from `test.py`, it will not run.

Comment: @LennartRegebro Actually, I have edited my answer regarding this

Comment: Yeah, it popped up just after I commented. Baleeteeed!

Comment: @Haidro - my goal is to print BranchName passed to test.py from test1.py,we can change the script too

Comment: @Haidro - is there a way to  fix it without removing if __name__ == '__main__'

Comment: @user2341103 Afraid not. Because when you import test.py, main() will not be called as `__name__ != '__main__'`

Comment: @user2341103 Actually, there is. If you get rid of `test1.main()` in `test.py`, and then in `test1.py` you put `test.main()` before you do `print BranchName`, that will work